# Vue JS Cli project with a folder not affected by Vue Router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I've built a Vue Cli app and it will replace a current static site at the top level domain.

However, the current site it is replacing needs to be kept alive (and working) within a sub-folder. Ideally, when navigating to this sub-folder site, I would like to be completely isolated and independent from Vue.

Under normal circumstances I could probably utilise the `/static` folder, but for this task I cannot. The 2 projects cannot be mixed together in this way.

Ideal scenario:

- https://example.com (Vue Cli project)
- https://example.com/my-page/
  (Vue Cli project)
- https://example.com/another-page/ (Vue Cli
  project)
- https://example.com/old-site/ (Legacy static project)
- https://example.com/old-site/my-page/ (Legacy static project)

Is this possible? At the moment if I do this, Vue Router will give me a 404 due to how my routes are set up at the top-level (wildcard route):

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'AppHome',
      component: AppHome
    },
    {
      path: '*',
      name: 'AppError',
      component: AppError
    }
  ]
})
```

I just basically want to allow linking off to a sub-folder on the server and not get Vue Cli / router involved.

Help much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have your webserver setup to route every request to https://example.com/* to https://example.com. This is necessary to let the vue router handle the routing wihtout having to put hashtags in every url (https://example.com/#/my-page).

In order to let your webserver return the old site when you make a request to https://example.com/old-site you'll have to configure your webserver so it returns that folder instead of serving https://example.com like you want with every other request. How you do this depends on the webserver you're using, but I'm sure you'll be able to figure that out.

Comment: Ah thank you. I guess you're right. It will need to be intercepted at the server level before any JS gets involved.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion this has no correlation with VueJS but with your webserver (Apache/Nginx).

In case of nginx you could just add new location

```
location /old-site {
   root /old-site-dir/;
   try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks...I'm using Apache, any ideas there at all?

Comment: Ugh... I'm not confident nor experienced with apache sorry. If you have time, I definetly recommend learning some basics about nginx. It is quicker and easier to configure.

Comment: Apache has Location directives too, I can't find a lot of documentation about it tho... https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#location

Comment: Apache configuration files are really a big headache.. really confusing...